# symbolic expression to numeric in matlab

Tags: matlab, double, symbolic-math

I need to do some calculation on the symbolic toolbox.

I have a value which is:

`q = sym('q%d', [n 1])`; where `n` is not a fixed value (it will be defined by the user)

I need to do some calculations on it such as:

```
for i=1:N
    z(:,i+1) = T_a(1:3,1:3)*z(:,1);
end
```

where (for `n=2` the value of T_a is changing for different n values)

```
T_a=[ cos(q1), -(4967757600021511*sin(q1))/81129638414606681695789005144064,                                          -sin(q1),    0;
 sin(q1),  (4967757600021511*cos(q1))/81129638414606681695789005144064,                                           cos(q1),    0;
       0,                                                           -1, 4967757600021511/81129638414606681695789005144064, 1/10
       0,                                                            0,                                                 0,    1]
```

and

```
z =

     0     0     0
     0     0     0
     1     0     0
```

when I run the code it gives an error and says:

```
The following error occurred converting from sym to double:
DOUBLE cannot convert the input expression into a double array.
If the input expression contains a symbolic variable, use VPA.
```

baed on the other question, I tried to use double command `q=double(q)`but it also didn't work.

How can I solve this problem.

Thanks in advance

Comment: Did you try to use `subs`: [http://www.mathworks.com/help/symbolic/use-subs-to-evaluate-expressions-and-functions.html](http://www.mathworks.com/help/symbolic/use-subs-to-evaluate-expressions-and-functions.html)

Comment: I also tried it and it didn't work

Comment: Can you post a minimal code sample that demonstrates the problem (i.e code that I can put in Matlab an execute).

Comment: I solved the problem while calculating all these values in symbolic. Thanks